# Too generic smarty error... can't narrow it down

Tags: php, compilation, smarty, prestashop

long story short: a module in Prestashop 1.6 throws a compile error. Now, the problem is that Smarty does not give me any info where to find it. Could anybody address me to the right file somehow, or at least to make a proper recursive search for something to correct, like a particular string? I see that there are problems having to do with

```
{* 
* 2007-2014
```

but I have them basically everywhere, as the tpl files have this copyright... Also, I am guessing what is xC3...

Thanks!

```
    Code:
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' in /home/compto5/public_html/e/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:667 Stack trace: #0 
/home/compto5/public_html/e/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php(3144): Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->trigger_template_error() #1 
/home/compto5/public_html/e/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php(3209): Smarty_Internal_Templateparser->yy_syntax_error(10, '\xC3') #2 
/home/compto5/public_html/e/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_smartytemplatecompiler.php(105): Smarty_Internal_Templateparser->doParse(10, '\xC3') #3 
/home/compto5/public_html/e/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php(206): Smarty_Internal_SmartyTemplateCompiler->doCompile('{*\n* 2007-2014 ...') #4 
/home/compto5/public_html/e/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php(187): Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->compileTemplate(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template)) #5 
/home/compto5/public_html/e/tools/sma in /home/compto5/public_html/e/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 667
```

**Update: I restored the smarty console in Prestashop 1.6, which is working good, but this particular page does not open the console, as it can't really load. I saw the function on line 667 and I really don't understand why it truncates the template file giving problems.**

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you should put here complete error message (the one in your question is not complete): `/home/compto5/public_html/e/tools/sma in /home/` - you removed some part of it.

You also mentioned:

```
{* * 2007-2014
```

if there is `{*` Smarty treats is as comment, so it needs to be closed using `*}`

The above will cause Smarty error but the following:

```
{* * 2007-2014 *}
```

makes that everything will be fine but it won't be displayed on page (Smarty comments are not displayed in page)

Comment: Thanks Marcin! Unfortunately this is indeed the complete message. But you are trying to tell me that maybe a comment is not closed?

Comment: @FabioRicci That's really strange. Indeed you should check if there is an unclosed comment or you have not included JavaScript in your tpl file (maybe you should use `{literal}`? ) But it's really hard to say if we don't see your template file. You should try remove content of some template files and narrow the error to one file if above suggestions won't help

Comment: Marcin, it is incredible strange. The problem is that I have literally hundreds of these templates. And the error does not point me to the one outputting this error... :(

Comment: @FabioRicci I get it but I don't know other solution